# How to reset entire system permissions back to default in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, security

I found I've a kind of messed up most part of my system permissions. Some places that only owner should have access is now exposed to world. How can I reset the folder permissions to default like i just installed a new OS?

I use Parrot GNU/Linux 4.5

Comment: You can't. Your system doesn't remember the original permissions. Unless you have backup, or you'll have to reinstall your system.

Comment: What directory is it? What did you do to mess it up?

Comment: my Downloads and Desktop majorly. I want to reset my Desktop to no1 can delete or tamper with files without being admin(sudo permission). and also my Downloads isnt accepting files now when i try to save like an image from browser

Comment: relateD https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: The only answer in this post is a good stating point to remedy the mess. My advise is to restrict most of the critical directories to the owner only. Then start opening to others only when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Download and Desktop folders are in your home directory, you should start by making sure the permissions in your home directory are all set correctly.
You want files in you home directory readable and writeable by yourself, so you can do (in a a shell):

```
$ chmod -R u+rw $HOME
```

You don't want your files readable by everybody, so you can do

```
$ chmod -R o-rwx $HOME
```

You might want your files readable by others in your group but not writeable:

```
$ chmod -R g+r $HOME
$ chmod -R g-w $HOME
```

This will get your home directory back to sensible defaults